# Unable to access textbox on an HTML form

Tags: python, forms, authentication, input, mechanize

I can't find the login text box. I can select the form, but i'm not able to find the input text. Can someone help me?

I'm trying to login automatically with this script on http://www.safilonet.safilo.com/
Thanks

Here is the code and the error message:

```
def login(self):
url = self._baseUrl + '/webapp/commerce/safilo/jsp/logon.jsp?lng=E&cpy=10'
self._br.open(url, timeout=30.0)
self._br.select_form(name='logon') 
print 'entrou'
self._br.form['login'] = self._username
self._br.form['password'] = self._password
self._br.submit()

if self._verbose: print 'Login successful.\n'

self.last_logged_in = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\billy\Projects\GlassInteg\trunk\src\run.py", line 90, in <module> go()
File "E:\billy\Projects\GlassInteg\trunk\src\run.py", line 39, in go ss = SafiloSupplier(updateBrands=True)
File "E:\billy\Projects\GlassInteg\trunk\src\GlassInteg\Supplier.py", line 283, in __init__
if login: self.login()
File "E:\billy\Projects\GlassInteg\trunk\src\GlassInteg\Supplier.py", line 307, in login
self._br.form['login'] = self._username
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 2780, in __setitem__
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 3101, in find_control
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 3185, in _find_control
```

mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'login'

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the page in question contains lots of invalid HTML, according to the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.safilonet.safilo.com%2Fwebapp%2Fcommerce%2Fsafilo%2Fjsp%2Flogon.jsp%3Flng%3DE%26cpy%3D10&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3)

As you can see, mechanize is not able to see the 'login' field:

```
>>> from mechanize import Browser
>>> br = Browser()
>>> br.open('http://www.safilonet.safilo.com/webapp/commerce/safilo/jsp/logon.jsp?lng=E&cpy=10')
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x1011cc638 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x1011cc488 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x1002bd650>>>
>>> br.select_form('logon')
>>> br._pairs()
[('merchant', '23888'), ('lng', 'E'), ('cpy', '10'), ('rightPageURL', 'http://www.safilonet.safilo.com/webapp/commerce/catalog/home.html'), ('password', '')]
```

If you have control over this page, fix the HTML ASAP.

However, I assume you don't, so here are some alternative options:

- use selenium
- try to login using a direct POST URL (not sure if mechanize supports this)

Comment: I've found a solution, now i suppose that it is selecting the input text box, but now I have another error:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`